# Where Are My Django Static Files?

Tags: django, apache

When I view my Django admin (after firing up the `python manage.py runserver` command), my admin section looks pretty & has CSS files in a static directory....somewhere.

When I look at the exact same admin area via Apache, it looks awful, 'cause the static files  are nonexistent.

- http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css (run via Django, exists)
- http://localhost/static/admin/css/base.css (run via Apache, doesn't exist!)

I'm assuming that the static CSS files are in some directory somewhere and the Django server can see them but Apache doesn't know where they are. So if I knew where Django keeps the CSS files, then I could put that path into the settings.py for static files. I have no clue where the files are being stored.... where are my Django static files?

Comment: I'd use the static files module to "deploy" them to a separate directory in you're www path https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks Josh, that's a great tip-n-link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Django's admin static files, look in:

django > contrib > admin > media

Comment: Thanks... I expected there to be a /static/ directory with that stuff in it, so I didn't peek into the /media/ one for it.

Comment: Np. You can find all sorts of interesting things by digging through the source code :)